# How to use freestyle project parameters in a Pipeline Project?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have an old freestyle project, and now trying to write a Jenkins file to run another job.
But I need to use some parameters from the old one. I tried different solution from documentation, none of them worked.

Q: How can I retrieve the old freestyle project parameters and use it in my Jenkins file?

The version is setting in the old one.in new one i have:

```
parameters { string(name: 'Version', defaultValue: '', description: 'test') 
string(name: 'JOBNAME', defaultValue: '', description: 'test') } .
```

Now I want to default value get set from the old freestyle job.

Comment: Is your freestyle job triggering your pipeline job?

Comment: No, I want them to have their own trigger.

Comment: Can you paste an example of parameter and how you are using it inside your pipeline as code.

Comment: Your requirement is still unclear. Is the freestyle job going to be decommissioned once you create this pipeline job? If you want a new version number each time, your freestyle job will need to create that version each time and in post build step, pass it as a parameter to the pipeline job and trigger the pipeline job.

Comment: It looks like you are asking for the freestyle job to set a global parameter, and then, whenever the pipeline job is triggered manually, it must consume this global parameter. This is not feasible, please use my suggestion above. The pipeline job needs to be a dependency job under freestyle job. The freestyle job will continue to be the parent job and both will run sequentially each time.

Comment: These plugins may help:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/
https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-env-propagator/

Comment: The plugin does not work.